# OwnerClass of C# Type "Point"?

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

This is a very quick (and probably noob) question.
I am creating a dependencyobject and one of my dependencyproperty will be a "Point".

The thing is that I don't know what is the "ownerclass" of the dependencyproperty i am creating :/
Here is the code :

```
    public Point MyPoint
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(MyPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPointProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPointProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyPoint", typeof(Point), typeof(**???**), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

And btw, the metadata is OK ? (there is a constructor that takes an int as parameter for "Point")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one example within the documentation for [`Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx), but hopefully its obvious enough - it's the class that you're adding this property to (you haven't show us your class declaration, unfortunately, so I can't post the *actual* value you need) but something like:

```
public class MySpecialClass {
    public Point MyPoint
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(MyPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPointProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPointProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyPoint", typeof(Point), typeof(MySpecialClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

If you're not sure on the MetaData, there's an overload of [`Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597500.aspx) that just takes three parameters, so you don't have to specify any metadata.